# Retrofit2 doesnt convert my object to GSON when I try to send it to server

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit

Whenever I click on my submit button trying to send username and message from text box to my url It gets rejected, I tried debugging response and it says that my message and body are null
Also, my header says that its still in HTML/UTF8 format

Here is my call, body, message and header log:

I/System.out: Call: true
    Response body:nullResponse message: , Response header:X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I/System.out: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Language: en
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 11:05:07 GMT
    Connection: close

Object

data class Post (
        @SerializedName("username") var username: String,
        @SerializedName("comment") var textBox: String)

Response

class WebUserData(
        var message: String,
        var status: String,
        var code: String,
        var id: String,
        var data: WebUser
)

ApiClient

class PostApiClient {

```
interface PostApiInterface{
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/posts")
    fun postCreate(@Body post: Post) : Call<WebUserData>
}

companion object {
    var mApiInterface: PostApiClient.PostApiInterface? = null
    private const val API_URL = "****************" (url)

    fun getApiClient(): PostApiClient.PostApiInterface {

        if (mApiInterface == null) {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build()
            mApiInterface = retrofit.create(PostApiClient.PostApiInterface::class.java)

        }
        return mApiInterface!!
    }
}
```

}

My Activity

class Feedback : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private var usernameHolder: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback)

        //PRONALAZI IME KORISNIKA, UZIMA KOMENTAR IZ BOKSA I POZIVA BUTTON
        usernameHolder = getUserFromId(1).username
        val username = usernameHolder.toString()
        val value = findViewById(R.id.fbfield) as EditText
        val textBox = value.text
        val submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.fbsend) as Button
        //===============================================================

        val editor = defaultSharedPreferences.edit().apply {
            putString("username" , username )
            putString("textBox", textBox.toString())
        }

        editor.apply()

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View) {

                println("POST CREATE: " + Post(username, textBox.toString()).textBox + ", " + Post(username, textBox.toString()).username)

                PostApiClient.getApiClient().postCreate(Post(username, textBox.toString())).enqueue(object: Callback<WebUserData>{
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<WebUserData>, t: Throwable) {
                        longToast("Saving trip failed.")
                    }
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<WebUserData>, response: Response<WebUserData>) {
                        println("Call: " + call.isExecuted)
                        println("Response body:" + response.body() + "Response message: " + response.message() + ", Response header:" + response.headers())
                        if(response.body() != null){
                            if(response.body()!!.code.toInt() == 201)
                                longToast("Trip data saved successfully.")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

}

Comment: Please look in *response.errorBody()* in your *onResponse*  method. It could provide some useful insight on your error

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for being late with my reply. This is what I get from response.errorBody(), even with toString = okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@c705d73

Comment: You can use debugger to look into the object contents